# Activate link upon reCAPTCHA success?

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I'm working on a WordPress site. Basically, I publish download links (PDFs), and would like to stop web crawlers from accessing this content. This led me to Google's reCAPTCHA. Can I use this alone, so that when a user clicks/answers correctly, the links on the page will be made active? I'm having trouble editing a page in WordPress to do this. Thanks.

-Rudy.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to show link dynamically after the verification of the recaptcha.

You can create a an ajax that fetches the link after the verifcation of recaptcha passes.
To do this, we will use WordPress ajax requests, [wp-ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)):

First, you register the ajax handler the request in the server side

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_hidden_pdf_link', 'search_hidden_pdf_link' );

// add this line to handle requests of non logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_hidden_pdf_link', 'search_hidden_pdf_link' );


function search_hidden_pdf_link() {
    // the response will be ajax response
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

   if(recaptcha_fails()){
   // writing the failure response
    echo json_encode(array('object' => 'error'));
    wp_die();
   }

   $secret_pdf_link = generate_pdf_link();

    // writing the succcess response
    echo( json_encode( array('object' => 'success', 'link' => $secret_pdf_link)));
    wp_die();
}
```

and in the front end, you create an ajax form, which asks and displays the link.

```
    <a href="#" id="hidden-pdf-link">PDF Link</a>
    <form id="pdf-link-form" action="<?php echo admin_url('wp-ajax.php'); ?>">
        <!-- some input that tells the backend which pdf to fetch -->
        <input type="hidden" name="public_pdf_id" value="<?php echo $pdf_id; ?>">
        <!-- the ajax request identifier, it is the suffix inside the action -->
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="get_hidden_pdf_link">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#pdf-link-form').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serializeArray()
                }).done(function (result) {
                    if(result.object == 'success'){
                        $('#hidden-pdf-link').attr('href', result.link);
                        form.remove();
                        alert('you can access the pdf')
                    } else {
                      alert('you are not allowed to access my pdf!!');
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @motie. I'm pretty novice at WP, but that first block of code should to in the `functions.php` file within the theme?

Comment: Also, this may be cumbersome if it's applying a different reCAPTCHA to each link.

Comment: @RudyM, adding the script to functions will work.
And for the recaptcha, you can use the same one for all links. All you have to do is to adapt the code snippet to send and display multiple links at once.

Comment: in the handler there's a function call `generate_pdf_link()`; what/where is this?

Comment: It is a function that fetches the pdf link(s) according to the form data. You will have to implement it to query the database according to the $pdf_id(s)